# How to compile a static library using makefile

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries

> I want to create a static library using Makefile in linux.

> I want to know if this makefile true or not ?
> I'm open to other ideas. Thanks all.

```
NAME= libamqp.a
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -c -Wall -g
SRCDIR := src
OBJDIR := obj
#definition des fichiers headers
INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/ -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp/dlo -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq 
#definition des librairies
LFLAGS := -L/usr/local/lib64
LDFLAGS :=
LIBS := -L. -lrabbitmq
SRCS_RAW := amqp_connexion.c amqp_consommateur.c amqp_deconnexion.c amqp_producteur.c amqp_outils.c

SRCS := $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW))
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW:.c=.o))


.PHONY: all
all: $(NAME)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est généré"

$(NAME):$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) $(INCLUDES) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
    ar rcs $(NAME) $(OBJS) 
    ranlib $(NAME)


$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDES)
    
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~  $(NAME)
    $(RM) -r  $(OBJDIR)
```

Comment: You should not include the `$(CC)` line in the recipe that creates the static library (that runs `ar`).  You use the compiler front-end to compile into object files, to link into executables, and to create shared libraries.  You don't use it when creating static libraries.

Comment: When asking questions please always provide the command that you invoked and the error messages you got.  Here you don't even describe what the problem is.

Comment: @MadScientist: Thanks for the response but what is the compiler front-end ?

Comment: In your case, `gcc`.  This is a program that manages the invocation of various other programs to actually complete the required command.  Building can involve running the preprocessor, running the compiler, running the assembler, and running the linker.  Rather than run all these by hand you use `gcc` to manage them for you.

Comment: @MadScientist: I haven't error messages, i want to know if the flags are correct or no, because i'm new with makefile.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site designed to help people who have specific problems get help for those problems after they've attempted to solve them for themselves.  It's not really geared for open-ended questions like "what's the best way to do XYZ" etc.  If you have a specific problem or a specific question about some particular thing, that's reasonable.  It's not a place to post a bunch of stuff and ask people to review it to see if there's anything that could be done better.

Comment: @MadScientist: I say , i'm not sure about my makefile. Thnaks for your comprehension and reactivity.

Comment: Posting an entire makefile and asking for non-specific help is no different, other than in scale, than posting all your code and asking for someone to review it and tell you how it can be better.  That's not what StackOverflow is for: it's a problem solving facility not a code review facility.  If you have a specific problem, in that something does not work, that's a good question.  If you a specific question, like "do I need both these commands to build a library", that's an OK question.  Showing the entire file and asking for general thoughts and opinions isn't what SO is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NAME= libamqp.a
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
SRCDIR := src
OBJDIR := obj
#definition des fichiers headers
INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/ -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp/dlo -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq 
#definition des librairies
LFLAGS := -L/usr/local/lib64
LDFLAGS :=
LIBS := -L. -lrabbitmq
SRCS_RAW := amqp_connexion.c amqp_consommateur.c amqp_deconnexion.c amqp_producteur.c amqp_outils.c

SRCS := $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW))
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRCS_RAW:.c=.o))

#$(info DEBUG: SRCS=$(SRCS))
#$(info DEBUG: OBJS=$(OBJS))
#$(info DEBUG: EXEC=$(EXEC))

.PHONY: all
all: $(NAME)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est genere"

$(NAME):$(OBJS)
    ar rcs $(NAME) $(OBJS) 
    ranlib $(NAME)

#règle pour créer un répertoire d'objets s'il n'existe pas
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

#définir une règle implicite pour créer des objets dans leur propre répertoire
#(note - ordre uniquement la dépendance sur le répertoire d'objets)
#$< :premier_dependance $@:cible 
$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@ 
    
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~  $(NAME)
    $(RM) -r  $(OBJDIR)
```

Comment: You should delete this line : $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) $(INCLUDES) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) ----> because, we want to generate static library not a dynamic library

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist : You can see the problem occured.